# Windows-Store-App RichEditBox Markdown Highlighting

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, markdown, rich-text-editor, windows-store-apps

at the moment I'm trying to get into Windows Store App Development and I'm stuck at some point.
I want to implement sort of a "markdown language" like the one on stackoverflow to highlight certain parts of text input.
Besides that I want to give the user the ability to use different font colors on his text.
The RichEditBox seems to be the ideal control for this task, but I don't know how to detect markup entering on the fly.
For example when the user enters `**Test**` the text should be transformed to **Test** immediately.

I have tried to approach this by listening to the "TextChanged" event and looking if the user enters `**`. If this is the case and if he entered the sequence `**` already one time before, then I'm setting the character format of the text range from the end of the first annotation sequence (start marker) to the beginning of the second (close marker) annotation to bold.

But this solutions seems to be very quick and dirty.

My second thought was to use the WebView control to render the text after preprocessing it with "Markdown Sharp".
But then the user won't be able to edit text.

So I need to get some advice or tip on approaching this problem. I also looked into writing a custom RichEditBox control, but I have no experience in custom control development and there aren't that many resources on the web for Windows 8 development for now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, your problem is that you want to edit the "source" based on Markdown syntax AND show the formatted result in the same place. How would you revert **Test** to regular, as long as the asterisks are gone? If the answer is "using a button" then why not use the button to make it bold in first place?

However, you could do a hybrid thing: apply formatting in the source text, while maintaining the Markdown markup (not sure if this is entirely doable for all Markdown tricks, though). That is, `**Test**` would look in the source like **`**Test**`**. For the final, formatted result you would use a separate view, such as RichTextBlock.

In order to do the hybrid formatting, an option would be to have a background thread matching regularly the whole text against regular expressions specific to the Markdown syntax. For each match the corresponding text range would then be formatted accordingly.

Comment: Couldn't you watch for the cursor position, and if it falls within the range of your bolded word **Test** you could replace it with \*\*Test\*\*